# Use Geometry Nodes to Deform a Curve by the Shape of Another Object

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a ground plane will some hills. I also have a curve object. I want to use Geometry Nodes, to deform the curve, and give it the same shape as the ground plane that is underneath it. Sort of the same effect as a shrinkwrap modifier, but I want to do it with Geometry nodes. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's a perfect use case for the raycast node:

[image]

result:

[image]

Note: the z-offset isn't necessary. I just put a little offset there so that the line is better visible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I re-created your node setup, but couldn't get the same result. Would you possibly be able to upload the Blender file so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: i will help you if you provide your blend file with your failed try. If you rebuild it exactly as my provided node tree, it will work.

Comment: Hey, I took a break and then came back to it and tried it again, and it worked this time. Don't know what I was doing wrong, but its working now. Thanks for your help!